# How do I make keyword shuffle on pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to make longer extension keywod that `bale cale` mean the same with `cale bale`, all keyword on string

Here's my dataset

```
Keyword         Category_1 Category_2 Category_3
ale bale cale   bale       cale       cale
bale cale       cale       cale       ale
```

Here's what I want

```
Keyword         Category_1 Category_2 Category_3
ale bale cale   bale       cale       cale
ale cale bale   bale       cale       cale
bale ale cale   bale       cale       cale
bale cale ale   bale       cale       cale
cale ale bale   bale       cale       cale
cale bale ale   bale       cale       cale
bale cale       cale       cale       ale
cale bale       cale       cale       ale
```

Comment: Is your keyword a string?

Comment: @kerwei my keyword is all on string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) with splitted values and flatten list comprehension, then join values together by space and add index value to helper `DataFrame` - `df1`. Last [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) original DataFrame:

```
from itertools import permutations

L = [(' '.join(y), k) for k, v in df['Keyword'].items() for y in permutations(v.split())]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['Keyword','idx']).set_index('idx')
print (df1)
           Keyword
idx               
0    ale bale cale
0    ale cale bale
0    bale ale cale
0    bale cale ale
0    cale ale bale
0    cale bale ale
1        bale cale
1        cale bale
```

Another solution for `df1`:

```
vals, idx = list(zip(*L))
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Keyword':vals}, index=idx).rename_axis('idx')
```

---

```
df = df1.join(df.drop('Keyword',axis=1), on='idx').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
         Keyword Category_1 Category_2 Category_3
0  ale bale cale       bale       cale       cale
1  ale cale bale       bale       cale       cale
2  bale ale cale       bale       cale       cale
3  bale cale ale       bale       cale       cale
4  cale ale bale       bale       cale       cale
5  cale bale ale       bale       cale       cale
6      bale cale       cale       cale        ale
7      cale bale       cale       cale        ale
```